# Deleting Custom Objects

Tags: custom-object, relationships, master-detail, delete

I have three connected Custom Object I'm trying to delete. When I attempt to delete them, I get the following message.

*'Your attempt to delete .... could not be completed because it is associated with the following relationships with other objects.'*

Now, I've deleted all the data and fields contained within this object so there's no fields connecting them left. However, I still get this message.

I've read up that you need to ERASE the deleted fields, but I don't seem to have access to this feature.

Any advice!?! Very lost with this..

Answer (score 5):

When you go to the "Custom Fields & Relationships" section of the custom object definition, there will be a bold link labeled "Deleted Fields (#)". If you click on that link, it will take you to a page where you will see the "Erase" option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Martin, I had to switch back to Salesforce Classic to do this! All resolved now.

Comment: @JamesPowell No problem. Glad I could help.